# JavaScript returns NaN even if input is an integer

Tags: javascript

I am typing an integer in the input box and it still returns 'NaN'.

```js
function goldenFunctiona() {
  a = document.getElementById("sidea");
  parseInt(a, 10);
  b = ((a + a) * (Math.pow(5, 0.5))) / 2;
  document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = b;
}
```

```html
<div id="top">
  <p>Side a =</p>
  <input id="sidea" type="number">
  <button id="button" onclick="goldenFunctiona()" type="button">Find side b</button>
  <p id="b"></p>
</div>
```

I don't know what's going wrong but it's probably something really simple.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: To clarify the below answers, ALL form elements are ASCII strings.  If you need to get an integer value, you need to do a conversion.

Comment: `a` is the element, not the input value. Try `parseInt(a.value, 10)`

Comment: And better to set innerHTML to `b.toString()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document.getElementById("sidea")` doesn't returns a *number*, but an *element*. 
Use `document.getElementById("sidea").value` instead to get the element value.

So:

```
function goldenFunctiona() {
    var sideaVal = document.getElementById("sidea").value;

    var a = parseInt(sideaVal , 10); // Get parseInt's return value or 'a' will still be a string
    var b = ((a + a) * (Math.pow(5, 0.5))) / 2;

    document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = b;
}
```

Comment: Cleaner even would be `a = parseInt(document.getElementById("sidea").value), 10);` (Reassigning variable a to completely different variable type is not so clean).

Comment: @wintvelt now its clean.

Comment: since its not HTML, you could use textContent, its faster and safer.. *although i don't see how this function could return anything dangerous in the first place